# Lazy GString evaluation while being executed by Eval or GroovyShell

Tags: groovy, eval, lazy-evaluation, groovyshell

For a monitoring system, I need to evaluate custom checks which are represented by boolean expressions. For example, I have a simple pseudocode condition (they can be more complex):

```
if (webservice is unavailable) and (there are no emails about planned downtime)
```

If possible, I'd like to use [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) here, so that if webservice is available (and the first condition is `false`), the second part won't be evaluated, as the overall result will be `false` anyway. Due to this, I can avoid connecting to mail server (and other time-consuming operations) when it's unnecessary.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class WebserviceDownCheck {
  boolean check() { 
    println 'Checking webservice'
    return false 
  }
}

class NoDowntimeEmailCheck {
  boolean check() { //shouldn't be executed
    println 'Checking emails'
    return true 
  }
}
//using string evaluation, because conditions are constructed during runtime
Eval.me("${new WebserviceDownCheck().check()} && ${new NoDowntimeEmailCheck().check()}")
```

The output is:

```
Checking webservice
Checking emails //shouldn't be there
Result: false
```

`NoDowntimeEmailCheck().check()` shouldn't be executed, because the first condition is already `false`.
I've tried:

- using `GroovyShell` instead of `Eval`
- changing `check()` methods to fields and applying `@Lazy` transformation
- changing `${new WebserviceDownCheck().check()}` to `${ -> new WebserviceDownCheck().check()}` (saw it [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/GString-lazy-evaluation-tp2803175p2803199.html))

Seems that I need some lazy mechanism which will allow me to initialize `GString` while `Eval` (or `GroovyShell`) is already executing it. Maybe something like lazy `Binding` for `GroovyShell`.

I wonder, is it somehow possible without writing custom string evaluation logic?

Comment: Have you tried `new WebserviceDownCheck().check() && new NoDowntimeEmailCheck().check()` without wrapping each in their own evaluation block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine it into one expression, like this:

```
Eval.me("${new WebserviceDownCheck().check() && new NoDowntimeEmailCheck().check()}")
```

and only the first will be evaluated if the result is false.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think about that, thanks a lot:)